# Is Enable or disable API access for Google Workspace Domain still available?

Tags: google-workspace

Sometime back there is an option in Google Workspace where we can disable API access for a particular Google Service to the whole domain completely. Like Admin Console -> Security -> API permissions -> API access -> {GoogleService} -> Enable or Disable. Refer this [link](https://help.syscloud.com/api-access-disabled-for-g-suite-domain) for better information.

But now, I can only restrict users to install the app, or restrict an App to access limit or block or full access to user data, or restrict App access to user data that are not listed in Manage Third-Party Apps. But I couldn't find the option to restrict data for a Google Service completely now.

So my question is, did Google removed that option from Google Workspace or did they changed the option to some other Option or is that option still available? If it is, where I could find that?